# document.write() and localStorage is not available in chromeApp

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-app, pdftron, chrome-app-developer-tool

Hi I am creating chroma app using pdftron webviewer.js.I am able to render pdf on browser.but When I am including pdftron webviewer library in my chrome app the I am getting some error. This is web version pdftron webviewer control.

[PDFTronWebViewer Sample](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/samples/viewing/)

I am getting this error:
1)document.write()and localStorage are not available in packaged apps.  throw new Error(message);

Answer (score 3):

`document.write()` and `localStorage` are [not available in Chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated).

As simple as that. You'll need to use a library that doesn't rely on those.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding window.localStorage in your index.js file you can make changes to lib/HTML5/ControlUtils.js to change how the _storePreference and _getPreference functions work.  Instead of having them use localStorage (which is not available in Chrome apps) you can use Google's storage API https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage  i.e.

```
_storePreference: function(key, value) {
  chrome.storage.local.set({key: JSON.stringify(value)});
}
```

If you prefer, you can override these functions in your config.js file i.e.

```
window.ControlUtils.userPreferences._storePreference = function(key, value) {
  chrome.storage.local.set({key: JSON.stringify(value)});
}
```

Comment: And that won't work, because `chrome.storage.local` is not a drop-in replacement of `localStorage`. It is asynchronous while `localStorage` is synchronous.

Comment: There's also a `document.write()` problem according to OP.

Comment: thanks Xan & Ryan , I have created sample for this I am getting two error like localStorage and document.write(). can we resolve this issue. This is my sample :- https://jumpshare.com/v/LVWrorMVVkJJB7XvcidN

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.write` you should use `document.createElement`